# 'but' for contrast and 'but' for opposition

Tags: adverbs, conjunctions

*But* does not mean the same thing in

> I like pop music but my parents like classical music.

and in

> My parents have played a lot of classical music to me but I still don't like it.

What is it called in each case?

Why can the first *but* be replaced by *whereas*, but the second cannot? Or, the other way round, the second *but* can be replaced by 'despite which/in spite of which' but not the first?

Comment: I submit that this has nothing to do with *but* and everything to do with *whereas*. (And that one doesn't work in the second sentence because of the "to me".)

Comment: Got my butts spanked!

Answer (score 0):

It does mean the same thing in both cases.

"But" is an oppositional word, and it just so happens that you've given two examples of opposition - one in which two different sides oppose each other, and one in which one side and a neutral side oppose one another.

There is nothing different about the two uses of the word.

Answer (score 0):

The first 'but', which can be replaced by 'whereas' is called 'a contrastive but' in French (no idea of cause and effect relationship between my tastes in music and my parents').
The second 'but', which can be replaced by 'in spite of which/despite which', is called 'an oppositive but' (the idea of cause and effect is present here, although my parents' enjoyment of classical music is a cause which remains inefficient, still has not succeeded in influencing me).

Both **but** are conjunctions.

The first one is a **coordinating conjunction**: the sentence could be turned the other way round… "My parents like classical music but I like pop music." It is a **but-whereas**.

The second one is a **subordinating conjunction**. The sentence… "I don't like classical music but my parents have played a lot of it to me.*" does not work! You would need 'even though', 'although', 'while', here, subordinating conjunctions which introduce the inefficient cause. The **but-despite which** can only introduce the absent or opposite effect: I do not like classical music.

'Despite which' is an adverbial phrase, which shows that there is no other subordinating conjunction that can substitute for 'but'.